# Spreading props on a React component with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

New to Typescript + React and I'm trying to spread props on the root node of `ListItem`. For example, I'd like to allow `data-*` and `aria-*` attributes for this component. Below is an example component that represents the issue I'm having.

```
import { forwardRef, HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface ListItemProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  disabled?: boolean;
  active?: boolean;
  href?: string;
}

const ListItem = forwardRef<HTMLLIElement, ListItemProps>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    active,
    disabled,
    className,
    style,
    children,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <li // throws error 
      ref={ref}
      style={style}
      {...other}
    >{children}</li>
  );
});

export default ListItem;
```

I'm getting this typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; href?: string | undefined; defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: string | string[] | undefined; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean | undefined; ... 249 more ...; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, HTMLLIElement>'.
  Type '{ children: Element; href?: string | undefined; defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: string | string[] | undefined; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean | undefined; ... 249 more ...; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>'.
    Types of property 'inputMode' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"text" | "none" | "tel" | "url" | "email" | "numeric" | "decimal" | "search" | undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"text" | "none" | "tel" | "url" | "email" | "numeric" | "decimal" | "search" | undefined'.
```

Comment: Probably complaining because `HTMLElement` differs from `HTMLLIElement` change the `HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` to `HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>` that might fix it.

Comment: Hmm didn't end up working

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have the variable used as `inputMode` as `string` (either by annotation or inference).

## Fix

Use the annotation `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>['inputMode']` (which uses a [lookup type](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0zc_fx3vkk)).

Fixed code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { forwardRef, HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface ListItemProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  disabled?: boolean;
  active?: boolean;
  href?: string;
}

const ListItem = forwardRef<HTMLLIElement, ListItemProps>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    active,
    disabled,
    className,
    style,
    children,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <li // throws error 
      ref={ref}
      style={style}
      {...other}
    >{children}</li>
  );
});

// Issue with inputMode
let asString = "text";
const error = <ListItem inputMode={asString}/>;

// Fix 
let correctType:React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>['inputMode']  = "text";
const ok = <ListItem inputMode={correctType}/>;
```

Comment: I had an issue with an Input component barking about not using one of its enumerated types, yet I could find an `enum` to use as a type.  THIS solved my problem `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>['inputMode']`.. THANK YOU!